# Setting Multiple Variables in SQL in one Query?

Tags: sql

I have the following line of code.

```
UPDATE account 
SET BlockMessage='$BlockMessage', SET BlockAdmin='$AdminUsername', Status=2 
WHERE ID='$ID'
```

As you can see in trying to set a "BlockMessage, BlockAdmin and Status" in 1 single query. The Infomation is correctly displayed if I echo the 3 individual Variables. however, when running the SQL String it only updates the Block Message row.

Any Ideas?

Comment: That statement is invalid SQL. `SET` may only be used once in an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `SET`. Update should be something like this:

```
UPDATE account 
SET 
  BlockMessage='$BlockMessage', 
  BlockAdmin='$AdminUsername', 
  Status=2 
WHERE ID='$ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use the keyword `SET` only once like

```
SET BlockMessage='$BlockMessage', 
BlockAdmin='$AdminUsername', 
Status=2
```